# javascript game character mouse movement

Tags: javascript, movement, vector

When a mouse button is pressed, coordinates are stored and character begins to move towards that point.

I do a check each frame if my character reached the destination, but because of the nature of how it all works, it can never be perfectly accurate. When I normalize my vector and multiply it by speed, I will always end up around that point but never directly at it. The bigger the speed, the more distance is passed in one frame and the further I get from where I wanted to be.

```
let startX = 110;
let startY = 110;
let endX  = 400;
let endY = 200;
let speed = 5;

let dx = endX - startX;
let dy = endY - startY;

let length = Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);

dx /= length;
dy /= length;

dx *= speed;
dy *= speed;
```

So this gives me a dx:4.775320684056187 and dy:1.4819960743622644, so that is the value that is added each frame, so in the end it gets to coords 399:191 next one is 404:193 etc. I have to pick a close one, or force object to move to the one I wanted, it never reaches exactly 400:200.

It becomes a problem when path finding and collision comes to play, because I can get 2 pixels on an obstacle etc.

How is this solved? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of for your pinpoint issue. You don't send an AI to walk exactly to a point. That is your first issue. You have to change the following:

On your AI/Pathfindining Agent, get the distance remaining to the target vector. If distance is lower or equal to defined radius, the target aquired radius, then the agent has reached his target.

Then you could simply additianlly snap the object of the agent to the exact point or slowly interpolate the remaining distance as an example.

I hope this get's you into the right direction. It is nto that much you are missing